# How to modify a json object in sql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following json:

```json
{"john": 34, "alex": 56, "daniel": 90}
```

However I would like to add another value

```json
{"harry": 78}
```

or alter an existing value

```json
{"john": 39}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: maybe this post will help u  [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use concatenation operators without need of `JSONB_INSERT` or `JSON_SET` functions (*as having no extra nested elements along with extra keys*) such as

```
UPDATE tab
   SET jsdata = jsdata || '{"harry":78}'::JSONB || '{"john":39}'::JSONB
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4473421bcc2f13f935851af1ebc45e58)</kbd>