# Update jsonb column in postgresql

Tags: python, jsonb, postgresql-13

I am trying to update postgres column response_json(type: jsonb) with jsonb data

```
UPDATE test.product SET response_json={'a': '', 'b': ''} WHERE "product_id"=1
```

I get ERROR

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
  Position: 39
```

Comment: Did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500670/4653505)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double Quotes ""` instead  of `single quotes ''` like this -

```
UPDATE  test.product SET response_json='{"a":"" , "b":"" }' WHERE "product_id"=1
```