# postgresql complex jsonb update

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I need to update a jsonb object in PostgreSQL but am unable to identify the correct syntax for updating the same, below are the use cases for the same.

***Data in table***

```
Create table jsondata (id int, data jsonb);
INSERT INTO jsondata VALUES 
(1,'[{"cc": null, "subsectionid": 26}, {"cc": null, "subsectionid": 27}]');

SELECT * from jsondata;
```

***Use case:***

Want to update the value of cc where subsectionid =27

***Query tried:***

```
UPDATE jsondata
SET data = data || '{null: ["Lake Providence"]}'::jsonb
WHERE data->>'subsectionid' = '27'
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Instead of using a list of objects. can you use an array or object with tiems indexed by subsectionid?

Comment: Would be much easier to do this update if you stored the objects in separate rows, not in an array in a single row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the jsonb\_set index position dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69245244/how-to-make-the-jsonb-set-index-position-dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

I hope somebody comes along with a simpler answer, but this shows how I would break down the jsonb and then build it back up for the update:

```
with invars as (
  select 27 as subsectionid, 'Lake Providence' as cc
), els as (
  select j.id, ae.rn, 
         case (ae.el->>'subsectionid')::int 
           when i.subsectionid then i.cc
           else ae.el->>'cc' 
         end as cc, 
         ae.el->>'subsectionid' as subsectionid
    from invars i
         cross join jsondata j
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j.data) with ordinality as ae(el, rn)
   where jsonb_path_exists(j.data, '$[*].subsectionid ? (@ == $x)', 
           jsonb_build_object('x', i.subsectionid))
), newjson as (
  select id, jsonb_agg(els order by rn) - 'id' - 'rn' as newdata
    from els
   group by id
)
update jsondata
   set data = n.newdata
  from newjson n
 where n.id = jsondata.id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/daDASF8G)

Comment: I hope so too, but I don't think postgresql has any sort of JSON value selectors,  only key and index selwectors.

Comment: I don't think there can be a really simple solution for this, so this may be the best possible answer. I would say that it is a design mistake to use JSON in the database if you want to update individual attributes.

Comment: It gets simpler if you don't use a CTE for `invars`, and also if you use a subquery inside of the `UPDATE` clause instead of `GROUP BY` on a separate query. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since your top-level `jsonb` entity is an array, you can filter out the element you want to update, or rather pick everything but that in a [`jsonb_path_query_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.20.1.1.1), then add the replacement. [`@?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) (or [`jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.17.1.1.1)) let you pinpoint your targets with wildcards in [jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CnHbc6Xy)

```sql
UPDATE jsondata
SET data = jsonb_path_query_array(data,'$[*] ?(@.subsectionid<>27)') 
           || '{"subsectionid":27,"cc": ["Lake Providence"]}'::jsonb
WHERE data @? '$[*].subsectionid ?(@==27)';
```

Comment: Removing-then-adding has the downside of changing the order in the array

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) on the data, add the property to the object(s) where you want, then [`jsonb_agg`regate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) them back to an array.

```
UPDATE jsondata
SET data = (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE element->>'subsectionid'
    WHEN '27' THEN element || '{"cc": ["Lake Providence"]}'::jsonb
    ELSE element
  END)
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) AS element
)
WHERE id = 1; -- or data @> '[{"subsectionid":27}]'::jsonb;
```

Comment: It comes at the price of having to iterate through all elements in each `data`, but if there can be more than one element with `"subsectionid":27` in a single `data` and/or any of the elements could have other fields except `cc` and `subsectionid`, this still works, handling both of the cases - [unlike my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75873938/5298879).

Comment: @Zegarek How can you not iterate through all elements in the array? Postgres has to built a new one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

json_set function.

```
CREATE TABLE jsondata (
    id int,
    data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO jsondata
    VALUES (1, '[{"cc": null, "subsectionid": 26},  {"cc": null, "subsectionid": 27}]');

INSERT INTO jsondata
    VALUES (2, '[{"cc": 1, "subsectionid": 26},     {"cc": "world", "subsectionid": 27}]');
```

---

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        (jsonb_array_elements(t.data)) ->> 'subsectionid' AS subsectionid
    FROM
        jsondata t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) - 1 AS ord
    FROM
        cte1
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        string_to_array(ord || ',cc', ',')
    FROM
        cte2
    WHERE
        subsectionid = '27')
UPDATE
    jsondata
SET
    data = jsonb_set(data, string_to_array, '"Lake Providence"', FALSE)
FROM
    cte3
WHERE
    cte3.id = jsondata.id
RETURNING
    *;
```

main idea from:
`select jsonb_set('[{"cc": null, "subsectionid": 26}, {"cc": null, "subsectionid": 27}]', '{1,cc}', '"Lake Providence"', false);`