# how to add more key/value item into a json field in psql/postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column named SALE in a table named HOUSE which contains below JSON:

```json
{
   "houses":[
      {
         "houseId":"house100",
         "houseLocation":"malvern",
         "attribute":{
            "colour":[
               "white",
               "grey"
            ],
            "openForInspection":{
               "fromTime":"0001",
               "toTime":"2359"
            }
         },
         "priceRange":null
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to replace `"priceRange":null` with `{"fromAmount": "100","toAmount": "1000"}`

```json
{
   "houses":[
      {
         "houseId":"house100",
         "houseLocation":"malvern",
         "attribute":{
            "colour":[
               "white",
               "grey"
            ],
            "openForInspection":{
               "fromTime":"0001",
               "toTime":"2359"
            }
         },
         "priceRange":{
            "fromAmount":"100",
            "toAmount":"1000"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried many different queries but was unable to get the desired results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)

Comment: What if your `houses` array contains multiple elements? Should this be done for all of them? Only the first? Or the last? Or the 42nd?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements`:

```
select jsonb_build_object('houses', 
  (select array_agg(case when (v.value -> 'priceRange')::text = 'null' 
      then v.value::jsonb || '{"priceRange":{"fromAmount": "100","toAmount": "1000"}}'::jsonb 
      else v.value::jsonb end) 
  from json_array_elements(h.sale -> 'houses') v)) 
from house h
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b3eeee282ba6aade7cf03600d51a74ad).