# Postgresql generic trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, primary-key

I am new to Postgresql, so please indulge if my question makes no sense.

I am trying to find a way to migrate my DB structure to Postgresql, in particular, I find functions quite convenient and would like to make my numerous triggers easier to write.

In my DB, I use the standard `last_modified` and `last_modified_by` fields to keep track of changes. I also use a standard primary key with incremental sequence.

There is built-in syntax to link sequences to primary key id's, but as I have to write triggers for the `last_modified` fields anyway, I was wondering if it was possible to have a generic function to update all at once.

Example:
Table `ANIMAL` has fields `AMIMAL_ID` (primary key, with sequence `SEQ_ANIMAL`), fields `LAST_MODIFIED` and `LAST_MODIFIED_BY`.

Similarly, I have a table `PLANT` with fields `PLANT_ID` (primary key, with sequence `SEQ_PLANT`), fields `LAST_MODIFIED` and `LAST_MODIFIED_BY` again.

I would like to create a generic function to be called in the 4 triggers I need to create. I was hoping to get something like this:

Before insert function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRIGGER_BI(p_pkField text, p_Sequence text) RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
        curtime timestamp := now();
BEGIN
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED := curtime;
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY := current_user;
    NEW.p_pkField := nextval(p_Sequence);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Before update function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRIGGER_BU() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
        curtime timestamp := now();
BEGIN
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED := curtime;
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY := current_user;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

And now, the triggers of table `ANIMAL`:
Before Insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ANIMAL
BEFORE INSERT
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TRIGGER_BI("ANIMAL_ID", "SEQ_ANIMAL");
```

Before Update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ANIMAL
    BEFORE UPDATE
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TRIGGER_BU();
```

Triggers of table `PLANT`:
Before Insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PLANT
BEFORE INSERT
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TRIGGER_BI("PLANT_ID", "SEQ_PLANT");
```

Before Update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PLANT
    BEFORE UPDATE
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TRIGGER_BU();
```

Is it possible, in any way, to get something generic this way?

**YES!** What is the correct syntax? 
BONUS: it is event possible to have a single function to do all the work, with default empty parameters that, if empty, would not update the sequence.

**YES, BUT WAIT!** what are the down-sides of such an approach? (performance, security, anything else to be considered)?

**NO!** So I really need on function for each trigger?

**UPDATE:**
I explicitly create sequences because I may want to have *shared* sequences among several tables. The idea is to use the shared sequence as a unique parent table with several child tables having a foreign key on their primary key to the parent table. Don't hesitate to comment on this approach, but my basic understanding is that accessing a sequence's next value is much more efficient than having to manage foreign keys...

**UPDATE 2:**
I found some quite interesting stuff which nearly gets me there - only that my `setValue` function isn't working...

Here the generic trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TRIGGER_FUNC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    p_pkField  text;
    p_Sequence text;
    pkValue    int;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%I::int', TG_ARGV[0]) USING NEW INTO pkValue;
    p_Sequence := quote_ident(TG_ARGV[1]);
    IF pkValue IS NULL THEN
        SELECT setfieldValue(pg_typeof(NEW), TG_ARGV[0], nextval(p_Sequence));
    END IF;
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED := curtime;
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY := current_user;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

I found a hint to the solution of the `setValue` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722575/2490877) and tried adapting it, but it doesn't work - am I simply using a wrong call? Or can I use some additional knowledge in the method to make it simpler? (I already used the fact that I am setting a `bigint` value, but I might be able to do better?!)

Here the (non-working) code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.setfieldValue(anyelement, text, bigint)
 RETURNS anyelement
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE 
  _name text;
  _values text[];
  _value text;
  _attnum int;
BEGIN
  FOR _name, _attnum
     IN SELECT a.attname, a.attnum
          FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a 
         WHERE a.attrelid = (SELECT typrelid
                               FROM pg_type
                              WHERE oid = pg_typeof($1)::oid) 
  LOOP
    IF _name = $2 THEN
      _value := $3;
    ELSE
      EXECUTE 'SELECT (($1).' || quote_ident(_name) || ')::text' INTO _value USING $1;
    END IF;
    _values[_attnum] :=  COALESCE('"' || replace(replace(_value, '"', '""'), '''', '''''') || '"', ''); 
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE 'SELECT (' || quote_ident(pg_typeof($1)::text) || ' ''(' || array_to_string(_values,',') || ')'').*' INTO $1; 
  RETURN $1;
END;
$function$;
```

Comment: The triggers look fine to me. What happened when you tried them?

Comment: Do you have multiple users connecting with different database credentials? Or is `CURRENT_USER` just there for demonstration? (That is, do you have real users connecting to the DB or just applications?)

Comment: Consider that only the application is connecting and CURRENT_USER actually the user using the app (I still don't know if I want to create one DB user for each app user and handle login & credentials by DB users, or if I shall, in some way, pass the username into queries).

Comment: I'm not orthodox and I really like fresh perspective in programming. However your idea does not seem to be apt. Foreign keys are mainly used to control referential integrity. Built-in mechanisms implement it in the best way, while in your approach I cannot see such control. It is very difficult to come up with something better than solutions developed over the years and tested millions of times, especially in such fundamental features as primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 5):

**No** for manually setting default values for primary keys.
Declare your tables with primary key as `serial` (or `bigserial`) and use the built-in mechanisms to handle such columns. 
Do not bother about that the values of a primary key are not consecutive. 
Primary keys are only and exclusively for distinctly identify the row and not for anyting more.

Besides all, you cannot do this in that way because trigger functions cannot have declared arguments.

**Yes** for setting values of common columns in many tables. You can use the same trigger function for insert and update. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generic_trigger() -- function without arguments
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.last_modified := now();
    NEW.last_modified_by := current_user;
    RETURN NEW;     -- important!
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

create table table_a 
    (a_id serial primary key, last_modified timestamp, last_modified_by text);
create table table_b 
    (b_id serial primary key, last_modified timestamp, last_modified_by text);

create trigger table_a_trigger
before insert or update on table_a
for each row execute procedure generic_trigger();

create trigger table_b_trigger
before insert or update on table_b
for each row execute procedure generic_trigger();

insert into table_a default values;

select * from table_a;

 a_id |      last_modified      | last_modified_by 
------+-------------------------+------------------
    1 | 2015-10-26 19:14:34.642 | postgres
(1 row)
```

**Maybe** you have really important reason to set values for primary keys in a trigger (see  jpmc26's comment).
In that case the primary keys should be declared as `integer` (`bigint`) without `default expression` and the trigger function should look like this:

```
create or replace function generic_trigger()
returns trigger as $$
begin
    new.last_modified := now();
    new.last_modified_by := current_user;
    if tg_op = 'INSERT' then
        if tg_table_name = 'table_a' then 
            new.a_id:= nextval('table_a_a_id_seq');
        elsif tg_table_name = 'table_b' then 
            new.b_id:= nextval('table_b_b_id_seq');
        end if;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$
language 'plpgsql';

insert into table_a (a_id) values (15);
select * from table_a;

 a_id |      last_modified      | last_modified_by 
------+-------------------------+------------------
    1 | 2015-10-26 19:14:34.642 | postgres
    2 | 2015-10-26 21:15:49.243 | postgres
(2 rows)
```

Read more about [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: The trigger is not trying to assign "gapless" values. It **is** using a sequence, just like the `serial` column will

Comment: There is a possible use case: if someone specifies a primary key value manually, then the `DEFAULT` clause generated by a `SERIAL` will be ignored. Another user would get a mysterious error later down the line when the sequence generated the already used value. The OP may want to explicitly override the value or throw an error if someone tries to `INSERT` with an explicit surrogate key value. That would necessitate a trigger, I think. That's why I asked if the OP has users interacting with the DB directly; that's the only case where I think it makes sense to use a trigger over `SERIAL`.

Comment: Great answer. Note that the serial is convenient for many cases, but in my design (consider it bad or not, but it's how it is done), I have tables sharing a sequence - this makes it much easier than having common parent table with two foreign keys, which is closest to what I need. Ease with the above approach: I can decide, table per table, which is the sequence the trigger's calling method. I update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

### Auto-incrementing surrogate key

[`SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) would be preferable:

```
CREATE TABLE animal
(
    animal_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

Note that `SERIAL` is really just syntax sugar. It does a few things for you to save you the hassle:

1. Creates a sequence
2. Sets the `DEFAULT` of `animal_id` to fetch the next sequence value.
3. Creates an "ownership" relationship between the column and the sequence. (If you drop the table, the sequence will go with it.)
4. Makes the column `NOT NULL`.

There is a concern with using `SERIAL`, though. If someone `INSERT`s with an explicit value, then that value will be used instead of generating one from the sequence:

```
INSERT INTO animal (animal_id, ...) VALUES(50000, ...);
```

This is not something to be concerned about if you have applications connecting to the database instead of real users; developers know better than to explicitly specify a value they want to be generated. If, however, you have real users logging directly into the database, this can be a concern. The fact you reference `CURRENT_USER` makes me think this is possibly your use case. A trigger, as you suggest, will solve that problem:

```
CREATE TABLE animal (animal_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE SEQUENCE animal_id_seq;
ALTER SEQUENCE animal_id_seq OWNED BY animal.animal_id;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_animal_id()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.animal_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot specify animal_id on INSERT: %', NEW.animal_id;
    ELSE
        NEW.animal_id = NEXTVAL('animal_id_seq'::regclass);
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
  END
  $$
;

CREATE TRIGGER animal_insert_generate_pk
BEFORE INSERT ON animal
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE generate_animal_id();
```

(Note that I threw an error instead of overwriting if they explicitly tried to set the value. It's generally better to fail fast for your user than to silently change values they specify.)

You do need a `FUNCTION` per table for this, unfortunately, because each one will need to use a different sequence.

### Automatically updating the auditing data

Let me first address the `UPDATE`. Yes, you need a trigger for this. You *can* define a single function for all tables here, though:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_last_updated_columns()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF 
        NEW.last_updated IS NOT NULL
        OR NEW.last_updated_by IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot specify last_updated or last_updated_by: %, %', NEW.last_updated, NEW.last_updated_by;
    END IF;
    NEW.last_updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    NEW.last_updated_by = CURRENT_USER;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$
;

CREATE TRIGGER update_animal
BEFORE UPDATE ON animal
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE populate_last_updated_columns();

CREATE TRIGGER update_plant
BEFORE UPDATE ON plant
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE populate_last_updated_columns();
```

That leaves `INSERT`. Again, this depends on if you have real users connecting to the DB and writing queries. If **not**, then you should leverage `DEFAULT` for simplicity; again, developers are smart enough to not specify these manually and to just let them get filled in:

```
CREATE TABLE animal
(
    ...
    last_updated TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    last_updated_by TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_USER,
    ...
);
```

But if you have users connecting directly and writing their own queries, then it might make sense to use a `TRIGGER` to prevent them from specifying these values manually. You can reuse the same function as the `UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER animal_insert_last_updated_cols
BEFORE INSERT ON animal
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE populate_last_updated_columns();
```

Note that PostgreSQL allows you to define multiple triggers for the same event. (They get executed in [alphabetical order](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html).) In this case, I would prefer to go ahead and keep the triggers separate. Since these two triggers cannot possibly affect the same data on a given row, this would be easier to maintain. It reduces the amount of code and it means that changes to the `populate_last_updated_columns` function will update all triggers with minimum hassle. I would not be concerned about the performance of multiple triggers unless you expect dozens of `INSERT`s per second. If so, then benchmark and see if the performance impact is a problem for you.

Comment: Actually... I may have an idea to generalize that surrogate trigger. I'll have to think on it.

Comment: I did additional research and came up with a reasonably close solution to what I want - but it isn't working yet. Maybe Update 2 will give hints?!